# What is the best way to generate a password/pin like string using brute force method?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

I have a string of 7 characters. I'm supposed to generate all the combinations. But some combinations are more likely than others, I would like the more likely ones to be generated first.

If I iterate from AAAAAAA to ZZZZZZZ, it's very unlikely that AAAAAAA is a valid combination. But BZYEKSO would be more likely being a password (more weight).

What algorithm would allow me to iterate through all combinations and come up with a random key that most likely resembles a valid pin?

If the string was 4 characters, I can pre-generate all the combinations and then scramble it for a better effect. But when the string is 7 characters long (better yet make it include  numbers too). There's 36^7 combinations and there would not be enough memory to hold everything.

I'm thinking there's an encryption algorithm that can be used to randomly generate a string that is 7 characters long WITHOUT repeating. ie. I would iterate through the algorithm 36^7 times using 36^7 unique keys and it would give me a 36^7 random numbers that are of length 7 and doesn't repeat.

Is there anything for this that exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether this is a reasonable thing to do, it *is* possible to enumerate a large set with a random order without having to store them all in RAM. Basically, you need a permutation over your source set (the 7-character strings, of size 36<sup>7</sup>) such that the permutation "looks randomish" and can be evaluated efficiently on each element. Such a permutation would be known as a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher).

Usual block ciphers use large binary blocks, i.e. work on the set of sequences of 64 or 128 bits, not on the set of sequences of 7 characters; however, other constructions are known which can bring decent security for such "small", non-binary blocks. This field of research is called [format-preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). Rogaway's [Thorp shuffle](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/thorp.pdf) is one of the rather easy to implement proposals, and has decent efficiency.