# Is there an easy way to generate all variations around a password?

Tags: passwords, password-management

I did something quite stupid while renewing my Keepass master password: a typo.
I quickly checked what I did type before validating but I obviously overlooked something because it simply doesn't work anymore.
It is not a file corruption problem (my other .kbdx files are fine, so are all the key files) and I've started testing some possibles typos with no luck so far.
Since I don't have neither the computing power nor the 50 millions year ahead of me (as explained [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50930/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-password-pin-like-string-using-brute-force-me)), I've looked for a way to **methodically generate a dictionary file with all variations around the original password** in order to brute-force my .kdbx file. I just found this goes way above my scripting capabilities :(
What I do know is:

- It looked good so I'm quite sure there is no more than one typo,
- the password is 15 chars long (plus or minus the typo),
- the central portion of the password is 5 digits and I'm sure this part is OK, the problem must be in the 5 chars before or after.

What I don't is there to go from here... So if somebody as already done something similar or can provide any help, I would be quite grateful (and so will be the community of distracted people!)
(if you ask: I'm not entirely stupid: I do backups so I've only lost 2 weeks of new passwords... I just don't like it then computers win!)

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while ago and I considered doing a bruteforce attack on the system, I got all the way to creating my own file to base the attack from and realised that I'd just have to end up typing out possibly hundreds of different variations of the same password, you might as well just manually type them out as it would save time...

Or just accept the loss and reset like I did.

Comment: OK, this one is on me: the fricking computer won...

Comment: @ubik Sorry no one else answered, I'd try and repost under a different name or try a different site, thought you would have had a lot more bites than just mine